# Simple Autoload class and include example

Tags: php, include, autoload

Ok im trying to get my head around autoload and i am a bit confused, i read a bunch of posts and now i think i am more confused, if i had a simple example i think i could get my head around it.

So lets say i have this simple project:

var/www/myproject/index.php

Then i have var/www/myproject/classes/database.php with this:

```
class Database {
    function __construct() {
        echo 'This is my Database Class <br />';
    }
}
```

And also var/www/myproject/classes/functions.php with this:

```
class Functions {
      function __construct() {
          echo 'This is my functions class <br />';
      } 
}
```

And also var/www/myproject/classes/users.php with this:

```
class Users {
      function __construct() {
          echo 'This is my user class <br />';
      } 
}
```

Then lets assume i have 2 includes here:

var/www/myproject/includes/header.php

var/www/myproject/includes/footer.php

So how would i autoload all those files and classes. Im thinking something like this but the examples i come across seem very specific to their setup or only apply to one folder, or include namespace which i haven't grasped.

I was thinking my index might look something like this:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
    require_once 'classes/'.$class_name . '.php';
}
```

But then that wouldn't work for includes for header and footer so maybe something like this is more appropriate

```
$path = array('classes/','includes/');
foreach ($path as $directory) {
    if (file_exists($directory . ? . '.php')) {
        require_once ($directory . ? . '.php');
    }
```

The idea being that it would include everything in the directory it finds but i am not sure how to do it, the ? was supposed to represent a wildcard and i understand this wont work, im trying to give an example of what im trying to do.

This must be something people come across a lot and im sure there is a good solution, just cant find an article that explains it well enough for me to understand

Comment: What are the contents of the header and footer? Autoloading applies to classes, but not really to HTML markup includes like headers and footers tend to be. Further, autoloading is used to locate class files for inclusion _once_, while a header or footer might be included multiple times during script execution. For those, consider instead just defining a function that knows how to look for `myproject/includes/{$name}.php` It really is a different concept than class autoloading.

Comment: ok that is helpful, probably explains why i wasnt finding a suitable answer as i was basically looking for 1 solution to 2 different problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use in your project namespaces i would recommend to use simple code:

```
 class ClassLoader {

      public  function handle($class) {
         $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $class.'.php');
         if(!file_exists($file)){
             throw new \Exception('class '.$class.' file not exists');
         }
         include_once $file;
     }

 }

 $autloader = new Classes\ClassLoader;
 spl_autoload_register(array($autloader, 'handle'));
```

// from now you can load all Classes from directories specified in namespace of class for example

```
 /////////////////////////////////////////////
 // directory => framework/classes/User.php //
 /////////////////////////////////////////////

 namespace framework\classes;
 class User {
     public function helloWorld(){
             echo 'hello World';
     }
 }

 //////////////////////// 
 // and here index.php //
 ////////////////////////

 $autloader = new Classes\ClassLoader;
 spl_autoload_register(array($autloader, 'handle'));
 $user = new \framework\classes\User();
 $user->helloWorld();
```